# How to make a simple ContentDialog in .xaml?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

What would it take to create a ContentDialog?

I basically have a button. When I tap that button the ContentDialog opens. The ContentDialog shall include a text like "this is an example" and 2 Buttons. How does the `<ConTentDialog></ContentDialog>` have to look like? Example:

```
<Page
    x:Class="PDFViewerSDK_Win10.PDFReaderPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:PDFViewerSDK_Win10"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" SizeChanged="OnSizeChanged">

    <ContentDialog x:Name="test" PrimaryButtonText="Ok" SecondaryButtonText="Cancel" Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}" Tapped="OnOptionItemTapped" >
        <Image Source="Assets/images/icon_menu.png"/>
    </ContentDialog>
</Page>
```

Comment: If you're wanting a button click to trigger the showing of your ContentDialog, I'd imagine you'd also have a Button in your XAML that has a Click event (that handles the showing of ContentDialog) tied to it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A content dialog can be easily created in your code-behind. You can then have that C# code run on the click event for the button you mentioned you wanted.

Your other option is to create a content dialog on XAML, as you already posted in your original question, so that when the button is clicked, you just refer to the content dialog on your code-behind and call the `ShowAsync()` method.

I could write example code in this response, but in the interest of this question being relevant to visitors in the future I encourage you to refer to [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialog#examples) which will be better maintained. I already read it and it does have specific examples that will be of great help to you.

**Edit:**
Posting sample code as a reference.

`MainPage.XAML`:

```
<Grid>
    <Button 
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Height="100" Width="250"
        Content="Show Content"
        FontSize="30px"
        x:Name="ContentBtn"
        Click="ContentBtn_Click"/>

    <ContentDialog x:Name="ContentDialog"
        Title="This is an example"
        PrimaryButtonText="Ok"
        CloseButtonText="Cancel"
        DefaultButton="Primary">
    </ContentDialog>
</Grid>
```

`MainPage.XAML.cs`:

```
private async void ContentBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        await ContentDialog.ShowAsync(); 
    }
```

Comment: Hey. So I went trough the MS Docu a bit. I were able to create a ContentDialog. I used the second example with  "termsOfUseContentDialog". I dont understand how to Change this Code for my Needs. I made smth like this (not complete, not enough Characters):
<Button x:Name="test">
<ContentDialog PrimaryButtonText="Ok">
<ContentDialog.TitleTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<TextBlock Text="test">
</DataTemplate>
</ContentDialog.TitleTemplate>
</ContentDialog>

and my cs would look like this:

OnOptionItemsTapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventsArgs e)
{ if (Name.Equals("test")) {} }

Comment: I have updated my response with an example I wrote and ran myself which does exactly what you asked in your original question. When asking anything in the future, please avoid posting blocks of code as a comment, choose to update/edit your question instead so that it is more readable. Please mark as answer if it is what you are looking for!

Comment: Thank you for your help. It worked out. Also thanks for the tips in general

Comment: @axbeit Have in mind: For a cleaner code/project structure you should define your ContentDialog in an own .xaml (and .xaml.cs). Another benefit is, that you can reuse the same dialog in multiple pages